# PhonegapOCRPlugin is not scanning photo

Tags: cordova, ocr, phonegap-plugins

I created a `phonegap/Xcode` project and added `PhonegapOCRPlugin` with its dependencies.

When I run the project, I see the `"Capture Editable Photo"` button in the screen.

But after I take the photo of a business card and use it, nothing seems to be happening. Have

I missed anything? I am using `cordova-2.5.0rc1`.

Thanks.

Comment: Last time I updated the plugin was for phonegap 2.2, I will try this afternoon and update if I found something. Next time open an issue on github, it's easier for me to track the problems

Answer (score 1):

Just tested and it's working on phonegap 2.5.0

The only problems I had
1. I had to remove the armv7s from valid architectures.
2. I had to add this line to the config.xml because the readme was for older version using Cordova.plist

```
<plugin name="com.jcesarmobile.OCRPlugin" value="OCRPlugin" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Have you also tested this in Android?

Comment: No, it doesn't work on android, is iOS only. It shouldn't be difficult to create a new android plugin because tesseract works on android, but I don't have android experience with plugins to do it

Comment: Just tested on Phonegap 2.7 with above answer.

Comment: @Paul, did it work? I think it shouldn't, work on 2.7.0, I have to update the plugin. BTW, with the current version there is no need to remove armv7s

Comment: @jcesar It does work on 2.7. I did overlook that and didn't remove armv7s from my project. Tested on an iPhone 4s, iOS 6.1.3, Xcode 4.6.2, OSX 10.8.3